# Kohana and OpenX

Tags: .htaccess, kohana, openx

I am trying to install OpenX in a website that I use Kohana. It worked fine, until I found this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable
>   to find a route to match the URI:
>   500.shtml ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [
>   635 ] thrown in
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/plugb/system/classes/kohana/request.php
>   on line 635

The url is: 
http://www.plugb.com/openx/www/admin/plugins/oxMarket/market-campaign-edit.php?clientid=1&campaignid=

My current .htaccess is:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.plugb\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.plugb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.plugb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Redirect 301 /gamesindex /
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Thank you,
Gabriel.

Comment: That error suggests that you were getting another internal server error (and the server tried to generate the 500 error response, but the request was grabbed by the Kohana route handler since the `ErrorDocument` doesn't really exist). So, to fix this fully you need to resolve the internal server error too. What does your server's error log say?

Comment: [23-Aug-2010 20:21:40] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: 500.shtml ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 635 ]
  thrown in /home/bianconi/public_html/plugb/system/classes/kohana/request.php on line 635
[23-Aug-2010 21:05:21] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: 403.shtml ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 635 ]
  thrown in /home/bianconi/public_html/plugb/system/classes/kohana/request.php on line 635

And other lines similar to this.

Comment: What about Apache's error log though? That appears to be PHP's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error stopped appearing after 24h.